# Can I tell with preprocessor code is in an mbed library or program

Tags: c++, mbed

The mbed forums are broken, so I'm posting here for some help.

mbed supports libraries and programs as separate entities.  In the spirit of module testing, I want to incorporate a test routine with my libary code.  If the library is imported as a program and compiled, then the main() would get built and linked, and generates some test output.  If the library is used normally, the main() is not built into the code, preventing linker errors.

are there any predefined preprocessor directives that I could look at to make this determination?   If not, does anyone have a suggestion on how I might implement a test routine into my library?

For clarity, here is a simple example:

[Here is a link to the library/program in mbed if you want to experiment/pull request suggestions](http://developer.mbed.org/users/glansberry/code/ExampleLibrary_Program/)

example code that wants to know if it is a program or a library

```
#include "mbed.h"

class LED_TEST:public DigitalOut{
   public:
   LED_TEST(PinName pin):DigitalOut(pin) {};

   void TurnOn() {write(1);}
   void TurnOff() {write(0);}
};

#ifdef __IN_A_PROGRAM   //if I'm compiling as a program then I want to create this main for testing.
                        //if I'm compiling as a library I do not want the main to prevent linker problems
int main(void)
{
LED_TEST lt(LED1);
    while (1)
    {
        lt.TurnOn();
        wait(1);
        lt.TurnOff();
        wait(1);
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: Don't ever use double underscore followed by a capital letter: symbols of that form are reserved.

Comment: I know nothing of mbed, but why you will not just separate this into two files: first for libary, and second for tests, and second `#include`s or otherwise uses the first?

Comment: thanks for the note about the double underscore.  But it was really meant to imply that I want something like this from the compiler that tell me whether it is being built in a program folder or a library folder.  I have been doing what you suggest, but it means that every project requires both a program folder and a library folder, and I want to merge these together if possible.

Comment: Look at the code for libc. Technically, (almost?) everything includes it as a library. But... From `man libc`: "       The pathname /lib/libc.so.6 (or something similar)  is  nor‐
       mally  a  symbolic  link  that points to the location of the
       glibc library, and **executing this pathname** will cause  glibc
       to  display  various information about the version installed
       on your system.
"